# How do I sum a column without pandas?

Tags: python-3.x

is there a way to get a sum of a specific column without pandas?
the data is now read as a list. so I would love to select a specific and sum it.
thanks

Comment: You can call `sum()` on an iterable like a list

Comment: thanks nathan.. the sum isnt working as I am finding it hard to select the column.

Comment: A b c
2.  E.   3
1    d.  3
2.   C. 4
 I want to sum c

Comment: I apologize if I'm misunderstanding your question: could you provide the structure of your data and/or what is impeding your attempt at selecting the column? If you have a dataframe column, you can extract it as a list instead of a series by running `df['colname'].to_list()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.